# GraphQL Object mapping Apollo with different schema by target

Tags: ios, swift, mapping, graphql, apollo

I have a project with multiple targets.

I have implemented Apollo to request database with GraphQL. Targets have slightly the same schema with some differences: +1 or 2 fields depending targets.

I can successfully build my app because I have changed my build phases to build only *common.graphql and *targetname.graphql

So when target A has AnnuaireFragment like that:

```
fragment AnnuaireFragment on Directory {
    id
    test
}
```

and target B has AnnuaireFragment like that:

```
fragment AnnuaireFragment on Directory {
    id
}
```

Everything can build, fragments are separated.

I would like that when I use translater I can build too. Can I use only one translater for the two targets?

```
static func translateFromAnnuaireNode(annuaireNode: GetAnnuaireFromSearchQuery.Data.Directory.Edge.Node) -> ContactModel {
            let contactModel = ContactModel()
            contactModel._id = annuaireNode.id
            // Here that doesn't build for target B because annuaireNode.test doesn't exist
            contactModel.test = annuaireNode.test

            return contactModel
}
```

How can I successfully build my app for target A and B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building for target B, the compiler doesn't know about existence of different class definition of `GetAnnuaireFromSearchQuery.Data.Directory.Edge.Node`, which is specific to target A. Which means that this error is compile-time error, and the only possible way of solving it is addressing it in compile-time.

The possible solution  I can come up with is to use different compilation conditions for different targets.

The setup is following:

1. Under build settings on one of your targets place `TARGET_A` and under another one place `TARGET_B`

[image]

2. Use `#if` to differentiate targets during compile-time

   ```
   static func translateFromAnnuaireNode(annuaireNode: GetAnnuaireFromSearchQuery.Data.Directory.Edge.Node) -> ContactModel {
       let contactModel = ContactModel()
       contactModel._id = annuaireNode.id


       #if TARGET_A
       //The code here will only be compiled when building target A
       contactModel.test = annuaireNode.test
       #endif

       return contactModel
   }
   ```

Comment: You are right, that works, thanks ! :) I wait to see if there are another solutions, if not, I will check as accepted answer !